# AWS Lambda ResourceConflictException during the deployment

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, hashicorp

We started to get ResourceConflictException during the deployment of our Lambda function. We create our Lambda via Terraform and our previous versions are:
AWS -> "v2.70.1", Terraform -> 0.11.7

AWS suggests using AWS version "v2.70.1" to solve the issue. And this version works with Terraform version 0.11.15

I did the upgrades. But still, I am getting the same error after the version upgrades. We have a VPC setting for the Lambda. When we remove it, we are able to deploy but with these settings we get ResourceConflictException. Do you have any idea how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the entire error message, or is that it?

Comment: This is the full error:
An update is in progress for resource: arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:OUR_ID:function:FUNCTION_NAME(Aws::Lambda::Errors::ResourceConflictException)

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug & it seems adding the depends_on call on some of your resources may fix it: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5154 - Eventually upgrading your terraform version should help too & there's a lot of good docs with hashicorp on moving from v11 to v12.